# Problema al conectarme a un ESP8266 desde una aplicacion de angular, petición sin respuesta

Tags: post, https, response, esp8266

Estoy trabajando en conectar un proyecto desde `angular` hacia un `esp8266`, estoy enviando un `json` el cual contiene un id y un action.

De momento para validar que tenga conectividad y los datos se estén pasando de manera correcta solo estoy imprimiendo en consola el contenido del `json` y retornando una respuesta hacia `angular`.

Pasa lo siguiente, de manera local utilizando el `protocolo http` me funciona sin problema, pero al subir al servidor me genera error, por lo que modifique el código para apuntar al `puerto 443` y pueda recibir solicitudes `https`, al momento solo he realizado testeo desde `Thunder Client`, dentro del testeo no me arroja error alguno, pero tampoco respuesta, se mantiene procesando la petición y ahí se mantiene.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con el problema que se me presenta, proporciono el código que estoy utilizando, gracias...

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServerSecure.h>

// Certificado SSL
const char* sslCert =  R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

const char* ssid = "INFINITUM3C7D";
const char* password = "FQxbG6eCaE";

ESP8266WebServerSecure server(443);

void handlePostRequest() {
  if (server.method() == HTTP_POST) {
    if (server.hasArg("plain")) {
      String jsonPayload = server.arg("plain");
      // Aquí puedes procesar el JSON recibido
      Serial.println("JSON recibido: " + jsonPayload);

      server.sendHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
      server.send(200, "text/plain", "Datos recibidos correctamente");
    } else {
      server.sendHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
      server.send(400, "text/plain", "Error: Falta el payload JSON");
    }
  } else {
    server.sendHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    server.send(405, "text/plain", "Método no permitido");
  }
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi conectado");

 // Imprime la dirección IP asignada al ESP8266
  Serial.print("Dirección IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Configurar certificado SSL
  server.getServer().setRSACert(new BearSSL::X509List(sslCert), new BearSSL::PrivateKey(sslCert));

  // Configurar manejador para ruta POST
  server.on("/prueba", HTTP_POST, handlePostRequest);

  // Iniciar servidor
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("Servidor HTTPS iniciado");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo implementar mqtt para realizar el enlace, de esa manera puedes desde cualquier parte acceder a través de tópicos, reducir y enviar información, control lo qu

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No cuento con privilegios en el servidor en el que estoy trabajando, por lo que no me es viable la opción del protocolo mqtt.